# VPN Configuration

Tags: vpn, tunnel, ssh

Im trying to reach a network at a remote site. I need to have my machine configured to have access to equipment on this network(not computers).  I have a debian machine located on this network but the firewall blocks most traffic/ports.  I have it configured to ssh reverse tunnel to a VPS I have.  I need to now be able to tunnel through to the remote network with my windows machine(must be windows to run software)

Like This

Windows Machine -> VPS(Public Accessible IP) -> Remote Debian Machine(Behind Firewall) -> Network of devices 192.168.1.x

I need  my windows machine to be able to communicate with the 192.168.1.x network as if it was on that network.

I don't know how to exactly do this.  So far I have established a L2TP/IpSec server on the VPS and can connect to it via my windows machine but I don't know how to connect this to the remote network.  I also dont know whether the L2TP server needs to be configured to 192.168.1.x subnet

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.